# Handling async actions with vert.x

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, vert.x

I wrote my Java web-service using vert.x, and I think I'm missing a few things regarding how the infra works.

I deployed a single verticle, let's call it HttpVerticle. inside, there is a single routing (`router.post("/dowork").handler(new MyHandler())`)

MyHandler is doing a very very quick pre-process action, and then send a message to the event bus.

There is a second verticle, WorkerVerticle, which is deployed when the HttpVerticle is deployed, and it consumes the event bus for messages from MyHandler. Here, there is a code which can be long (Waiting for REST api call / DB write / S3 write etc.), and when it's done I simply return `message.reply()` to MyHandler

When I try to work with ~150 concurrent requests it looks good, but when trying to go 200 and more, I start getting timeouts.
I Increased the number of instances for the HttpVerticle, and it helped.

What I don't understand, is why?
The thread of the HttpVerticle is basically doing nothing but writing to the bus, so it should be able to respond even to a 1000 requests, no?

My second question here is, if my pattern of Handler->write to bus->Verticle consume from bus is the right one, because I saw a second pattern of just using the Handler, without using the event bus

Comment: Can you post a few details about your code, how verticles are deployed, ...etc? It's difficult to troubleshoot a performance problem with little know facts. In particular, the name *WorkerVerticle* implies that events from this verticle are handled by the worker pool threads. Then the worker pool size could be a limitation.

Comment: Do you return immediately inside ``MyHandler`` using ``handler.response().end("ok")``? Or you just wait for the message from the ``WorkerVerticle``?